# Disabling the large file notification from google drive

Tags: download, google-drive-api

While downloading zip file(more than 25MB i assume) i am getting the below notification,

```
Sorry, we are unable to scan this file for viruses.

The file exceeds the maximum size that we scan. Download anyway
```

in the browser.Is there any option to disable it,so that i can download any large file directly without having to receive such messages as interruption.

Want to know whether any setting is there in the google drive, so that i can disable that broker message.

Comment: Well the problem is clearly defined in that error. The files are too big

Comment: If it works second time you click to download in the application, can't you just loop the download part?

Comment: @andy ya... you have any solution for that?

Comment: We can't magically know the code you have attached to your buttons, and telling people "when I push the button it doesn't work" isn't conducive towards getting a helpful response. Please edit your question to have all of the relevant details (and as little irrelevant items as possible).

Comment: @StuartM I am using this in my iPad application so..

Comment: @mah I am using ASIHTTPRequest for downloading.Befor i used to retrive the data from the FTP its working fine... But now client is askig Google Drive

Comment: @KundapraHudga Have you get any solution!I have same problem I am trying to play video in iPhone app which having more then 50MB sized and when I open link in web browser I got same error!!

Answer (score 12):

After spending many countless hours trying to get a direct download link that bypasses the virus scan I finally figured it out by accident. A URL in the format below along with your Google API key will bypass the virus scan. I could not find this documented anywhere ([here is the official doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)) so use at your own risk as future updates might break it. https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileid/?key=yourapikey&alt=media

You can also use the authorization access token from google oauth instead of the apikey.

Comment: It's documented here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

Comment: For someone who doesn't know how to use API key. Api key for direct downloads can be generated in Google cloud console. Follow [this](https://elfsight.com/blog/2020/03/how-to-use-google-drive-api-and-get-an-api-key/#getting) link to generate one.

Answer (score 10):

> *Obsolete: this approach no longer works after August 31, 2016*

I found that the following pattern allows to disable the large file notification:

```
https://googledrive.com/host/file-id
```

I think anyone knows how to find the **file-id** for Google Drive file.

Please keep in mind that this method works only if file is shared with "Public on the web" option.

But this feature is deprecated and will stop working after August 31, 2016:  http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html

Comment: Very nice, but what about the file name? Is there any way for this to give "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=..." - to enable correct download?

Comment: OK, this article - http://www.broculos.net/2013/04/how-to-use-google-drive-to-share-files.html - shows the solution to what I needed: in short, the way to go is `https://googledrive.com/host/folder-id/filename.exe` - when the folder is all published as "public on the web". BTW, such things like to be removed by google when you get most used to them.

Comment: I have created url as per instructions given in http://www.broculos.net/2013/04/how-to-use-google-drive-to-share-files.html#.Vd_fY9Oqqkp but still I m getting same error "Google Drive can't scan this file for viruses, Download anyway?", Did Google changed their policy and restricted it now? any other solutions please?

Comment: @AqibMumtaz what kind of URL are you trying to use? I have checked URLs like `https://googledrive.com/host/folder-id/filename` and they are working fine (without any error) to me.

Comment: I tried https://googledrive.com/host/0B-vtJ-ryRq6ffkhaNDFjempFQzdKOWNRQmRHdDViaWJrY2tkaExCQlhzQ1A5MzE4SkV5Q3M/test.pdf M I doing something wrong? Do you think I need to replace "host" with something?

Comment: @AqibMumtaz This link should work. Please make sure the folder is shared with "Public on web".

Comment: @VictorSharovatov I just changed permission from "Anyone with the link" to "Public on web", to all three level, parent folder, current folder and file itself, all of them are "Public on web", I m pasting final https://googledrive.com/host/0B-vtJ-ryRq6ffkhaNDFjempFQzdKOWNRQmRHdDViaWJrY2tkaExCQlhzQ1A5MzE4SkV5Q3M/test.pdf link in browser, it must start downloading file, dont know may be Google might have updated policy.

Comment: @CJBS the answer has an info that solution stopped to work since 2016. I'm not sure if it's a right approach to remove all the answers which don't work anymore but worked and helped before.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any longer a way to bypass Google Drive's warning that a file is too big to be scanned for viruses.

At one time Google Drive had web hosting support via webViewLink URLs that look like googledrive.com/host/[doc id].  But that feature is deprecated and will stop working after August 31, 2016.

http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/publish-site

Answer (score 1):

use `zip-extractor` to download file and extract to your Google Drive. It's offered as an option at the website you found the link at. You have to be logged in at Google Drive for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative is to use a [Google Cloud Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects).

1. Open the Cloud Storage browser in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
2. Create bucket that is Multi-Regional or Regional based on your need.
3. Upload the file o the bucket and make it public.
4. Use the public url to download the file using scripts, browser, gcloud commands, wget or curl.

This will work for any file size. Cloud Bucket service is really cheap. Google gives you free credits to start out and the bucket use can be well covered under the free credits.

Answer (score 0):

### WGET

```
export fileid=<file-id>
export filename=combian.rar
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id='$fileid -O- \
     | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1/p' > confirm.txt
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt -O $filename \
     'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id='$fileid'&confirm='$(<confirm.txt)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can bypass preview, virus scan, AND get the correct file name if you simply use the following link convention:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=yTib&id=FILE_ID

where the google drive file id replaces FILE_ID.

Thanks,
Mick

Comment: This is true for small files. For bigger files it shows the message.

Answer (score -2):

Well you can try "Download anyway"

If that doesn't work I have found with Gmail that by changing the extension to *.txt* it allows the file to be downloaded/transferred then when downloaded you can change it back to *.zip*

Comment: I am using this in my iPad application... there i can't do like that :(

Comment: Ahh, then I think you maybe stuck. Sorry not to be more positive. Do you not have a server you can upload it to or something? Maybe DropBox might allow it (or even the new Mega?)

Comment: ya we have...but the client is asking Google Drive only

Comment: Could you break up the folder to be two seperate, or even try a zip within a zip? Or possibly try compressing as a .tar archive (does much the same job as .zip)? I doubt any of those will work but worth a try if its worth keeping the client sweet? :)

Answer (score -2):

The way to go is to use the link format Mick suggested:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=CONFIRM_CODE&id=FILE_ID

The confirm Code ist valid indefinitely for each file. It does not change over time. So far the only way to find out the confirm code (or for that matter the complete link) is to curl https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID and then extract the link under the "download anyway" button, which includes the confirm code.

Cheers.

Comment: This does not work. Even when switching to a different browser, the link with `confirm` will redirect you back to the "Download anyway" page.

Comment: The confirm code changes every time you try to download / stream that file.

Answer (score -6):

you must disable virus scan from Chrome, but it will disable virus scan from all activities with the browser. In Chrome Preferences, show Advanced Settings and uncheck "Enable phishing and malware protection".