# Google Drive Rest API V3 Downloading large files (>25MB)

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to figure out how I can download a large binary file directly in the browser via the Google Drive API V3.

According to the [Drive API manual](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) there are three different ways to download files via the API:

1. Download a file — files.get with `alt=media` file resource
2. Download and export a Google Doc — `files.export`
3. Link a user to a file — `webContentLink` from the file resource

Option (2) isn't useful in my case as the files aren't Google Docs files and Option (3) isn't a solution as this will redirect the user to a warning that Google Drive can't scan big files for virusses.

This leaves me with option (1). This works almost perfectly and I can successfully redirect the user to the file via the alt=media attribute e.g.:

> https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0By3zfuC927VWRkJnV3g2aDY4UHM?alt=media&access_token=ya29.XXXXXXXXXXXXX

Although this will start the download in the Browsers, it will be named with the ID of the file instead of the original File Name. Which is quite confusing.

**So my question is:** How can I download large files (>25MB without virus warning) via the Google API with the right file name?

> **NOTE 1:** Downloading the file via cURL on the server before and
>   sending the output to the browser isn't an option in my case.
>
> **NOTE 2:** Furthermore, the files can't be shared. That's why I am using the API.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it's currently not supported for files that can't be shared and since web hosting support in Google Drive has been deprecated. (Reference: [here](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html?visit_id=0-636169549936478389-4058541463&hl=en&rd=1))

You may want to check the responses given in the following SO posts for additional information:

- [Disabling the large file notification from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728038/disabling-the-large-file-notification-from-google-drive)
- [wget/curl large file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive)

Comment: Well, it **is possible** to download large(non-shared) files via the API after the web hosting support has been deprecated as I showed in my question. However, the file will only be named with the ID of the file instead of the Title/Name of the document. So the question is not how to download those large files, but how download them with the right file name.