# Google Real-Time API: How to download real time file larger than 10MB?

Tags: google-drive-api

We are using Google real-time API for some internal communication. However, some of the files got bigger than 10MB. Now we are getting error "Requested Resource Too Large to Return" when trying to download it via the server (https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/realtime/ call).

Is there are a way to download this file using server API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can try to download the file in parts/chunks as what suggested in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41516612).

For further reference, you can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#partial_download) about partial download.

> Partial download involves downloading only a specified portion of a
>   file. You can specify the portion of the file you want to dowload by
>   using a byte range with the [**`Range`**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header. For example:
>
> ```
> Range: bytes=500-999
> ```